# Implementing backbone.js to retrieve category posts using JSON API

Tags: plugin-jetpack, json, backbone

***Note:** I reformulated this post after solving my original problem because I immediately ran into another problem that can fit under the same title. First I'll summarize the first problem and my solution, then continue with the second problem.*

My Wordpress 3.8 installation was set to work with Jetpack's JSON API. But my backbone.js GET requests were canceled (indicated by Google Chrome's Network Panel). Furthermore, I got this report in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/americawasnotfree.org/posts/?category=life-after-the-treaties. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://americawasnotfree.org' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Solution:** Use the [JSON API plugin from dphiffer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) instead of Jetpack's solution.

**NEW ISSUE:** Now even though I get the data, I have not figured out how to work with it using Underscore's templating framework. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsEw2i4wQMM). Below is my broken code (which includes code suggested by Dato'), and below that is what I've tried.

```
    <div class="posts"></div>

    <script type="text/template" id="posts-list-template">
        <div>Here is the...</div>
        <% _.each(yourListPosts, function(yourListPost) { %>
        <%= yourListPost.get('title') %>
        <% }); %>
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
      options.url = '//americawasnotfree.org/api/' + options.url;
    });

    var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Post,
        url:'get_category_posts/?slug=life-after-the-treaties/'
    });

    var PostsList = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.posts',
        render: function() {
            var that = this;
            var posts = new Posts();
            posts.fetch({
                success: function(posts) {
                        var template = _.template($('#posts-list-template').html(), {
                            yourListPosts: that.collection.models
                        });
                    that.$el.html(template);
                }
            })
        }
    });

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          "": "category"
        }
    });

    var postsList = new PostsList();

    var router = new Router();
    router.on('route:category', function() {
        postsList.render();
    });
    Backbone.history.start();
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I have modified the #posts-list-template in several ways:

1. Passed `posts` as the data argument in `_.template()`, then tried traversing the object using bracket notation: `posts["responseJSON"]["posts"][0]["content"]`. (If I assign the returned object to a variable from Google Chrome's console, I can get the the "content" of post number 0 using this notation.
2. Passed the fetched data through `jQuery.parseJSON( data )` (thinking the data might not be correctly parsed).
3. I know `_.template()` is correctly passing templates. The function succeeds in displaying a div and sample text when placed in `#posts-list-template`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to display the data returned from JSON using the code below.

Note that I used JavaScript bracket notation to access the posts array rather than Backbone's .get method. Also note that the object fetched is passed to a variable called posts, which is then passed to _.template. I'm betting it's this that prevents me from using Backbone's .get method, but I'll save the question for a separate thread.

```
<script type="text/template" id="posts-list-template">
    <div>Here is the...</div>
    <% _.each(posts, function(post) { %>
        <div><%= post['title'] %></div>
        <%= post.content %>
    <% }); %>

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
      options.url = '//americawasnotfree.org/api/' + options.url;
    });

    var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url:'get_category_posts/?slug=life-after-the-treaties/'
    });
    var PostsList = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.posts',
        render: function() {
            var that = this;
            obj = new Posts();
            obj.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    posts = obj["models"][0]["attributes"]["posts"];
                    var template = _.template($('#posts-list-template').html(), posts );
                    that.$el.html(template);
                }
            })
        }
    });

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          "": "category"
        }
    });

    var postsList = new PostsList();

    var router = new Router();
    router.on('route:category', function() {
        postsList.render();
    });
    Backbone.history.start();
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```